# How to get the clicklistener for textview in child for expandable list?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

I am currently using the custom layout for the child in Expandablelist which includes 2 different text views and an imageview. Also it will always have 1 child everytime. I am able to get the clicklistener in the adapter but not able to get this in the activity.

I have also tried to get the click listener event in the onChildClick() method but it was not working.

I am using this adapter in different activities so i want to have the click listener for one of the text view in the activity itself.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to get this done guys, i added `android:onClick="textClickHandler">` in the layout file and included the listener as below in my activity:

```
public void textClickHandler(View view){

        if(view.getId() == R.id.textMore){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "More Text Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will work only if you don't care what `TextView` from the `ExpandableListView` was clicked(from child at position 0, from child at position 7 etc).

Comment: @Luksprog - Yes this is what i want as mentioned in my problem statement i only have one child in the list. Thanks for pointing this out. I will try out your solution too for list of child sometime later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the listener on a `View` from the `Activity`(if I understood what you're trying to do). One way to do it would be to:

- make your adapter have a `boolean` value that you set when you instantiate the adapter(This will tell you if the adapter belongs to an `Activity` where the `TextView` should have a listener(for `true`, for example). If the value is `false` then you'll make sure not to set a listener on the `TextView`).
- set the the listener on the desired `TextView`(only if the previous value was `true`, for other activities you'll simple ignore this part) in the `getChildView` method of your custom adapter.
- in the `onClick` method for that view's `OnCLickListener` use the `Context` that you pass in the constructor of your custom adapter. Cast it to the desired activity and use it as you want. A more elegant way of doing this would be to let the desired `Activity` implement a custom interface(to notify you when the `TextView` was clicked). Then in the adapter make a field with the type of that interface that you'll set to point to your `Activity` when you instantiate the listener. When the `TextView` is clicked call the methods of that field above and notify the `Activity` that something happen and it should do some stuff.